# MS Access form is requerying every time I scroll

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access continuous form, one of the fields checks the count of files in a folder relevant to the record. These files are stored on a 12.5 Kbps (the speed of a floppy disk) Sharepoint server, so it takes about 7 seconds per record to query the number of files. And that's fine, except that any time I scroll up or down, it requeries the file count of the records that are newly visible on screen. This means I can't scroll past more than one record every 7 seconds.

What I'd like for the form to do is query ALL the records it would show in the continuous form, and then stop requerying them unless specifically told to.

The line for the data source is

```
WorksheetFileCount: FlrFileCount("\\vaww.visn21.portal.va.gov\sanfrancisco\education\EDADMIN\ProgramFiles\" & [ProgramID] & "\worksheet\") .
```

What I have tried so far.

1. Build a separate query for the data and direct the form to that query. Same result.
2. Build a report from the form. Same result.

EDIT: One particularly weird thing is that it doesn't actually query those folders until that area of the query is visible on screen. So if I put the folder query in the 10th column, and my display only shows 9 columns, it doesn't query the folders until I scroll to the right, at which point it queries all of them. So something in Access is querying JUST the records visible on-screen.

Comment: Can't you do a count first in a query and base your form on the query?

Comment: I've tried that. It still requeried on every line, and then froze for five mintues followed by a crash. Reproducible. The Sharepoint is powered by a hamster wheel.

Comment: Have you tried to select *snapshot* as RecordsetType for your query?

Comment: What trigger event is this query placed? Consider the `OnCurrent` event. So wherever the cursor lands, query runs.

Comment: Currently the query is just part of the datasource. I need to export reports of this data so I need the query to pull ALL the data. 
Here's what happens: Let's say I have room for 10 records on my screen for the query view. It will only query the files for the first ten records, then stop. When I scroll down, it queries the newly revealed records. When I scroll up, it queries the records again. I tested this by including a beep in the function that queries the number of files.

Comment: To further clarify, it's even exhibiting this behavior when I put the query as part of a datasource for a report. It will only check the folders of what is visible on screen, and then drag the system to a halt trying to run them for newly revealed records when scrolling down. I am going to try a function to export it to excel as a way to get it to all run at once, but it's... slow.